# Trying to select a variable from within a ForEach loop, and if that variable is less than a certain number, display another variable as Red

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, powershell-3.0

This is my first time asking a question on here so sorry if it doesn't make much sense.

I'm currently trying to a do a project in which I look up OS information, Disk Size, and Processor type and manufacturer of a list of servers, and output all of that information from a single variable. After that, if the free space of the server is less than 5gb, list the disk size of the server in red.

This is what I have so far as my script:

```
$ServerList = Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\Servers.txt

ForEach($Server in ($ServerList))
    {
        "Collecting server information on $Server, please wait..."
        Start-Sleep 3
        "Collecting Operating System..."
        $OSInfo = gwmi Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $Server | select Caption
        "Collecting Storage..."
        $StorageInfo = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Server | Format-Table DeviceId, @{n="Size in GB";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="Free Space in GB";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
        "Collecting CPU..."
        $CPUInfo = gwmi Win32_Processor -ComputerName $Server | select Name, Manufacturer
        $ServerInfo = @($OSInfo, $StorageInfo, $CPUInfo) 
        Start-Sleep 3
        "All done with $Server. Here's what we got:"
        $ServerInfo
        Start-Sleep 3
        "Continuing on to next server in the list..."
        Start-Sleep 3  
        break      
    }
```

This is an example of the output:

```
Collecting server information on *****, please wait...
Collecting Operating System...
Collecting Storage...
Collecting CPU...
All done with *****. Here's what we got:

Caption                                                                                                                                                                                       
-------                                                                                                                                                                                       
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise                                                                                                                                                   



DeviceId                                                                                                             Size in GB                                               Free Space in GB
--------                                                                                                             ----------                                               ----------------
A:                                                                                                                            0                                                              0
C:                                                                                                                         51.9                                                           5.35
D:                                                                                                                           15                                                           6.37
E:                                                                                                                            0                                                              0



Name                                                                                            Manufacturer                                                                                  
----                                                                                            ------------                                                                                  
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7- 2870  @ 2.40GHz                                                        GenuineIntel                                                                                  
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7- 2870  @ 2.40GHz                                                        GenuineIntel                                                                                  
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7- 2870  @ 2.40GHz                                                        GenuineIntel                                                                                  
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7- 2870  @ 2.40GHz                                                        GenuineIntel                                                                                  
Continuing on to next server in the list...
```

I want to do an If statement where if the number provided in `"Free Space in GB"` is less than 5, then it will display Size in GB in Red, else, display it in Yellow,

**ASK:**
I don't know how to go about actually pulling the number from "Free Space in GB" to use in the If statement. Any help?

**EDIT:**

I've edited my script using user TheGameiswar's answer, and am now running into a new problem with my output.

```
Collecting server information on *****, please wait...
Collecting Operating System...
Collecting Storage...
A: 0 0
C: 50 19.55
D: 35 18.16
E: 0 0
Collecting CPU...
All done with *****. Here's what we got:

Caption                                                                                                                                                                                       
-------                                                                                                                                                                                       
Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise                                                                                                                                                   




Continuing on to next server in the list...
```

The CPU output is being skipped and it is outputting the Storage information as that part of the script is ran, and not when the $ServerInfo variable is called. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-6) has a `ForegroundColor` parameter.  Ex: `Write-Host "Red Text" -ForegroundColor 'Red'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below

```
gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk  
| select  Deviceid,@{n="SizeinGB";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpaceinGB";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}  |
%{ Write-Host  -ForegroundColor $(if ($_.FreeSpaceinGB -le 5 )
 {"red"} else {"Green"}) $_.Deviceid  , $_.SizeinGB , $_.FreeSpaceinGB}
```

**References:**
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.06.windowspowershell.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/0797d236-eda4-4b40-b7aa-40f150af7653/how-can-i-color-a-column-in-powershell-output?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: I added this to my script and it is working sort of, but now the storage info output happens as soon as that line is reached in the code, it skips over the CPU info variable, and then doesn't post either the Storage Info or CPU Info when the Server Info variable is called. I added the full output to my question above.

Comment: Write-host doesnt work with variables, output is not stored

Comment: Is there any way to get write-host to store as a variable or is there a similar command I can use to reach the same result? That also doesn't explain why my CPU variable is now being skipped over either, unless it somehow accidentally got merged with the write-host.

Answer (score 0):

This script lists all mounted drives on the local computer.  You could integrate this inside your current loop.

The script doesn't need to be this long, however, I wanted to highlight the individual steps.

```
$drives = gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName .

foreach ($drive in $drives) {

    $freeSpaceKB = $drive.FreeSpace
    $freeSpaceGB = $freeSpaceKB / 1gb

    if ($freeSpaceGB) {

        Write-Host $drive.DeviceID, $freeSpaceGB
    }
    else {

        Write-Host $drive.DeviceID -ForegroundColor 'Red'
    }        
}
```

Comment: I've added this to my script, but I'm running into the same issue as above. I need to be able to put the information from Write-Host into a variable so that way OS info, Storage info, and CPU info is all posted at the same time from the ServerInfo array. Is there any way to do that?

Edit: Also, I'm having the problem where it's now skipping over my CPU info, and is only posting OS info from the array.

Comment: Sounds like your script has two distinct sections.  Data collection and then output.  You can add the `$drives` var to `$ServerInfo`, during collection.  Then build a loop that outputs the whole `$ServerInfo` var in one go.

Comment: I think I get what you mean. Run the first part in a ForEach loop for data collection, store all of that in the ServerInfo variable, and then output all of that information wherever I decide to put it (like a csv file)? Would I need to put the second part in a Do loop or would I be able to just put that outside the ForEach and it'd be fine?